# router.get() to a 'normal' async function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a nodejs app to test a feature that was created by a collegue and it was written as routes rather than function but i want to implement it as a function in the nodejs app that we have. the route file looks as such:

```
router.get('/', async function (req, res, next) {

    //do some things and create data

    req.pdf_data = data;
    next();

}, async (req, res, next) => {

    // fetch the number of pages that we need to scrape
    let pcount = req.pdf_data.numpages;

    //do more things

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify(fa, null, 3));
});

router.get('/test', async (req,res,next) => {

    //things are done 

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify(fa, null, 3));
});
```

I only included the lines in which res, req or next is used as im unsure how to convert it all to be a 'normal' async function like

```
async functionName(){
   //some things are done
   // maybe something is returned
}
```

I'm very new to javascript so any help is much appreciated and im unsure if this is something that is possible

Comment: no point in using `async` for functions that do not use `await` - read up on what async/await is, then you'll see you don't need all those async at all

Comment: @Bravo the above functions do use `await`, I just hadn't included it as I didn't believe it was relevent code to include :)

Comment: `router.get('/test', async (req,res,next) => { ... })` can be `router.get('/test', functionName)` - done ... if functionName is async or not is irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do it as simple as this, but please check the differences of normal functions and arrow functions. Some code might work differently.

```
async firstFunction(req, res, next) {
    //do some things and create data

    req.pdf_data = data;
    next();
}

async secondFunction(req, res, next) {
    // fetch the number of pages that we need to scrape
    let pcount = req.pdf_data.numpages;

    //do more things

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(JSON.stringify(fa, null, 3));
}


router.get('/', firstFunction, secondFunction);
```